# can I prioritize more exact matches when using ngram filter in search results?

Tags: elasticsearch

When using the ngram filter with elasticsearch so that when I search for something like "test" I return a document "latest", "tests" and "test". Is there a way to make it so that the "document exactly matching the query "test" is always returned higher up in the search results?

Answer (score 8):

That is a bit of an issue with ngrams: you get a lot of false positives in your ranking. A solution is to combine ngrams with shingles. Basically in addition to the ngrams, you also index the full word as a separate term or even combinations of words. Shingles are basically like ngrams but with words rather than characters.

That way, an exact match against the shingle terms scores higher than something that only matches the ngrams.

**Update**. Here's an example of a custom analyzer. After you define it, you can use it in your mappings. In this case I use the icu_normalizer and folding and my suggestions_shingle. All this is set as the default analyzer so all my strings are handled this way.

```
{
    "analyzer":{
        "default":{
            "tokenizer":"icu_tokenizer",
            "filter":"icu_normalizer,icu_folding,suggestions_shingle"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "suggestions_shingle": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 5
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh right, actually I'm trying to do the opposite, where something that matches the ngrams scores higher than words that may contain the ngram :\

Comment: Do you think you could show me an example of how to set this up?

Comment: @JillesvanGurp I am having same problem. When I use ngram tokenizer, I get a lot of results. I tried your example, but I am not getting expected results. For example, if my field contains term 'Test', and I search for 'tes', it should give me result, but it does not. What should be done for this?

Comment: If you want to compensate for minor spelling mistakes you would want to build that into your query by e.g. using the fuzzy parameter on the match query. That would combine well with the approach above which is about combinations of  correctly spelled tokens. Ngram creates a lot of noise. In your case it would generate te es st for 'Test' and te es for your query so it would be a partial match (assuming bi-gram). But a lot of other stuff might match as well. Tip, use elasticsearch-head or similar tool to see what token the analyzers generate for your mapping, text, and queries.

Comment: How do you use ngrams in combination with shingles?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the field content to fields via the mapping. Example:

```
  "fullName": {
    "type": "string",
    "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
    "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
    "fields": {
        "fullWord": { "type": "string" },
        "raw": { 
            "type":  "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
  }
```

Note that str_index_analyzer uses nGram here.
Then you can build your search to also search against these fields. Example:

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [{
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "firstName.fullWord",
              ...
            "query": query,
            "fuzziness": "0"
          }
        }],
        "must": [{
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "firstName",...],
            "query": query,
            "fuzziness": "AUTO"
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need multifield and multimatch query.

I have similar issue. I needed to search by first name, so if I put search term 'And', I get first 'Andy', and than 'Mandy'. With just nGram, I was not able to achieve that.

I added one more analyzer that uses front edgeNGram (code below is for Spring Data Elasticsearch, but you can get the idea).

```
    setting.put("analysis.analyzer.word_parts.type", "custom");
    setting.put("analysis.analyzer.word_parts.tokenizer", "ngram_tokenizer");
    setting.put("analysis.analyzer.word_parts.filter", "lowercase");

    setting.put("analysis.analyzer.type_ahead.type", "custom");
    setting.put("analysis.analyzer.type_ahead.tokenizer", "edge_ngram_tokenizer");
    setting.put("analysis.analyzer.type_ahead.filter", "lowercase");

    setting.put("analysis.tokenizer.ngram_tokenizer.type", "nGram");
    setting.put("analysis.tokenizer.ngram_tokenizer.min_gram", "3");
    setting.put("analysis.tokenizer.ngram_tokenizer.max_gram", "50");
    setting.put("analysis.tokenizer.ngram_tokenizer.token_chars", new String[] { "letter", "digit" });

    setting.put("analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.type", "edgeNGram");
    setting.put("analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.min_gram", "2");
    setting.put("analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.max_gram", "20");
```

I mapped the required fields as multiple field:

```
@MultiField(mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.String, indexAnalyzer = "word_parts", searchAnalyzer = "standard"),
otherFields = @NestedField(dotSuffix = "autoComplete", type = FieldType.String, searchAnalyzer = "standard", indexAnalyzer = "type_ahead"))
private String firstName;
```

For the query I am using multimatch were I first specify 'firstName.autoComplete', and than just 'firstName'

```
QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(searchTerm, new String[]{"firstName.autoComplete", "firstName"})
```

This seems to be working properly.

In your case, if you need exact match, perhaps instead of 'edgeNGram' you could use just 'standard'.

Comment: When I try to map the required as multiple field, I can't seem to resolve many attribute methods like `indexAnalyzer`, `@NestedField`, `dotSuffix`, `searchAnalyzer` etc. Is there something I might be doing wrong? I am using `Spring Data ES` and `Spring Boot`.