# Spring Data Elasticsearch only returning exact matches

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I made a simple project to test `free text search` using Spring Data Elasticsearch. Here is my entity:

```
@Document(indexName = "flag", type = "flag")
public class Flag {

    @Id
    private String flagCode;

    @MultiField(mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.String))
    private String flagName;

    // setters and getters
}
```

Now, my search operation looks like:

```
SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(fuzzyQuery("flagName", freeText))
            .build();
List<Flag> flags =  elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery, Flag.class);
```

With this, I am only getting objects whose `flagName` is exact match to `flagName` where as I want that if at least 2 characters match, it should be a **match**.

If relevant, my `DataConfig` file looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.shubham.dao")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.shubham.data")
public class DataConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String clusterName;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String elasticsearchHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int elasticsearchPort;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception {

    Settings esSettings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
            .build();

    //https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_transport_client_versus_node_client.html
    return TransportClient.builder()
            .settings(esSettings)
            .build()
            .addTransportAddress(
                    new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(elasticsearchHost), elasticsearchPort));
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

What am I possibly doing wrong? I am newbie to Elasticsearch.

Comment: What input are you trying to match?

Comment: @Val `freeText`. If flagName is "India", `freeText` can be In, Ind, Indi etc. But the match only occurs when the `freeText` is exactly "India".

Comment: Have you tried to search with lowercase `in`, `ind` and `indi`?

Comment: Surprisingly, when I search for `ndia`, I still get the object. But when I further remove characters like using `ndi` doesn't return anything. Seems like an issue with case of the string.

Comment: Yes, because there's only one edit hence why it works. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `fuzzy` query has a [fuzziness setting of `AUTO`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness), which means that

- if the term is between 0 to 2 characters long, it must match exactly.
- if the term is between 3 to 5 characters long, only one edit is allowed
- above that, two edits are allowed

In your case, when you index `India`, the token `india` (lowercase) will be indexed.

- Searching for `In` implies 4 edits => no match
- Searching for `Ind` implies 3 edits => no match
- Searching for `Indi` implies 2 edits => no match
- Searching for `India` implies 1 edit => match

You probably need to use [edge-ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) to tokenize your data instead of using fuzziness which is not at all suited to search for prefixes like you seem to be willing to do.

Comment: Well, I understand the concept of edit count and matches but how can I achieve this with `Spring Data Elasticsearch`?

Comment: You need to increase the fuzziness `fuzzyQuery("flagName", freeText).fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO)` but again this is not a good idea in my opinion and you should prefer doing this with ngrams.

Comment: Similar question, can you link an example of using `ngrams` with `Spring Data`? `Fuzzinees.TWO` works fine but I want to provide results which have a similar regex. On Edge Ngram page I found, `Edge N-Grams are useful for search-as-you-type queries.`. This is exactly what I am looking for but with `Spring Data`.

Comment: Quick search reveals this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384279/can-i-prioritize-more-exact-matches-when-using-ngram-filter-in-search-results/29661932#29661932